# AWS CLI Cloudformation - Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

When running below command from a dev linux box i am getting error "Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name sample-stack --template-body file://template.yml --parameters file://parameters.json --role-arn arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/SampleRole --region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

I am successfully able to run s3 commands (like aws s3 ls).
I tried "curl [https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"](https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/%22), it works. But "curl [https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"](https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/%22) times out.
Also telnet connects successfully.

```
telnet cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443
```

The aws credentials(iam user) with which i am running these commands has full access to cloudformation, s3 and iam.

Can anyone help to debug it further whether it is a permission issue or connectivity issue from the dev linux box i am using ?

Comment: Maybe the service was temporarily down. Did you by any chance check the status - https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Nope, service was up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there is a firewall rule on the dev box which was preventing this. So marking it resolved.